# How to use xml.dom.minidom to create and detect comments?

Tags: python, xml, dom

I have to write a program in Python that analyzes an XML file and comments out certain tags based on their content. At first, the task seemed simple enough to tackle without any XML parser, just string functions. Now, the complexity has reached a level too high to use string functions without making the code incredibly, unnecessarily cluttered and ugly. So, I'm turning to an XML parser, specifically xml.dom.minidom. I am not finding much in the docs on how to do what I want, so my two questions are:

1. How can I insert a comment around a tag using xml.dom.minidom?
2. How can I detect a tag has already been commented using xml.dom.minidom?

EDIT

One more thing: How can I then print out the text in the edited parsed XML object?

Comment: Why, out of all the XML parsers, you had to choose the most painful one?

Comment: In what way is it the most painful? I've observed it as the most simple, but if there are simpler ones for my needs, by all means, please do say.